# How to determine whether or not user sent MS Outlook message which was built from Java code?

Tags: java, outlook

In my program I create Outlook.exe process and send message with pre-populated contain. After sending message or closing message window I need to know whether or not user sent message.

`exitValue()` method of process doesn't help because exitValue in both cases is 0.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
Process process = processBuilder.command("C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\OUTLOOK.exe", "/a").start();
if (process.exitValue() == 0) {
    Session session = sessionExtracting();
    session.beginTransaction();
    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("UPDATE mailorder set mailordstatus = 2");
    query.executeUpdate();
    session.close();
}
```

Comment: This is probably not a question suitable for StackOverflow - I'd suggest you try asking on a Microsoft product forum, or perhaps on the [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) stack-exchange site.

Comment: @sillyfly - this is a perfectly valid question for SO.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Outlook is a singleton - if outlook.exe is already running, launching the second instance will simply transfer control to the first instance. Secondly, you are hardcoding the outlook.exe file location.

Use the Outlook Object Model (use a COM bridge) - create an instance of the `Outlook.Application` COM object, create new message using `Application.CreateItem(0)`, populate the message properties (subject, Body, Recipients, etc,.) and either call `MailItem.Send` or display the message using `MailItem.Display` and trap the `MailItem.Send` event.